# How to determine the problem in HDD reconnection?

Tags: server, usb-power, media-server, file-server

I have setup my raspberry as my media streamer server using minidlna. I have also auto-mounted the HDD using its UUID. It works but I have notice from time to time, the drive gets disconnected and reconnected, and it now fails in automounting, I have to explicit run the command

```
sudo mount/dev/sdb1 /media/Drive
```

I have also noticed, every time I cannot access `/media/Drive`, the hard drive changes its name (e.g. from `sda` to `sdb` to `sdc` to `sdd` to `sde` and so on).

How do I determine the problem? I have already setup an external powered usb hub, that's why my pi can power up the HDD. The pi is open for 24/7 also.

EDIT:

I did the following:

- Installed `ntfs-3g` so that pi will recognized my hard drive.
- Retrieve the UUID of my hard drive using `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`
- Created a directory for my drive: `mkdir /media/Mett`, and gave it `755`  permission.
- opened `/etc/fstab file`, and appended the line

  `UUID=01D031EB07CC4ED0 /media/Mett ntfs-3g uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007 0 0`

Comment: How have you "auto-mounted the HDD using its UUID"/

Comment: By doing this, www.techjawab.com/2013/06/how-to-setup-mount-auto-mount-usb-hard.html

Comment: Don't post a link. If you want help post WHAT YOU ACTUALLY DID.

Comment: This behavior strongly suggests that either your power supply or USB cable is electrically unreliable.

Comment: Then I did the following, refer the edit above

Answer (score 1):

Looks like my external HDD is faulty. I tried running a different external HDD to raspberry pi and it has not disconnected even once for a week already.

Answer (score 0):

Check your power supply. Make sure your adapter can handle at least 2A since you're running a hard disk. A phone charger won't do.

Source: Experience

Comment: I now used 5V 2A power supply for the raspberry pi. After sometime, the drive has moved again from /dev/sda1 to /dev/sdb1. 

What steps can I take to diagnose this problem?

Comment: As what everyone is saying here, you cannot diagnose it. It's part of the Linux kernel. I'll update my answer. Sit tight.

Comment: Do you mean there is no way to log or determine as to why the hard disk drives reconnects after some time when it was mounted? Is there really no command to do so?

Comment: @Xegara `dmesg`

Comment: It says: buffer I/O error on /dev/sda2, logical block 786554, async page read. What does this imply?

Comment: I also did full scanning of sectors and found there are many bad sectors. Using WD's utility, I performed low level wiping and low level scanning afterwards just to find out that there are no bad sectors left. So I mounted it to the rpi again and it happened again. So is there any implication on io buffer error?

Comment: @Xegara I will still suspect the power supply and/or cable. Have you tried running it a few hours on a desktop computer? Linux preferably, not virtualized.

Comment: If I were to use a dual USB A Male to micro USB B male Y cable for the WD passport, will it help? Or it will not do anything significant since the external HDD is already connected to the external powered hub.

Comment: @Xegara try adding `max_usb_current=1` to your `/boot/config.txt` file. Put it at the very bottom. Then, reboot and try to use the disk again.

Comment: But that setting is only available to B+ and Pi model 2. My rpi is only model B

Comment: @Xegara add it anyways. ⌐■_■

Comment: Done and additionally, I masked the VBus pin of the usb cable from the usb hub to the pi to prevent back feeding (pi powering from usb hub), thus bypassing the fuse in the micro usb power port of the pi (based from an article I read). So there are two power supplies, one supplies power to the pi and another to the usb hub. The latter does not give power to the pi. This was tested by plugging the latter power supply first and the pi did not power up until I plugged the first power supply. 
And yet it still got disconnected.. should I try the Y cable?

Comment: @Xegara Yes, try the Y cable. Anyways, have you tried to use it on a Linux PC for a few hours? Does it do the same on a PC?

Comment: I'll try them both on weekends. Thanks. Is ubuntu fine?

Comment: @Xegara Mmhmm, it should be fine on Ubuntu. Check `dmesg` from time to time and check for the buffer IO error or any USB-related errors.